# Any HTML5 Audio Recorders (alongwith an Audio Player)

Tags: html, avaudioplayer, recorder

I have discovered Universal HTML5 players like http://www.jplayer.org/ , but none of them have a record button. Wondering if there is one, similar to the one in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use video.js with [this plugin](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record) for recording audio/video
[image]
Here's the example:

```js
var player = videojs("recorder",
{
    controls: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    plugins: {
        wavesurfer: {
            src: "live",
            waveColor: "black",
            progressColor: "#2E732D",
            debug: true,
            cursorWidth: 1,
            msDisplayMax: 20,
            hideScrollbar: true
        },
        record: {
            audio: true,
            video: false,
            maxLength: 20,
            debug: true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<audio id="recorder" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></audio>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video.js" defer></script>
<script src="path/to/recorder/plugin.js" defer></script>
```